# I want to add commands (shell scripts etc.) to Eclpise Package Explorer or Navigator

Tags: eclipse, file, plugins, command, execute

I'm in desparate need for a functionallity I miss in Eclipse:

Right click on a file in Navigator (or a resource in package explorer) and execute a command on it, like "chmod a-w".

Google did not bring anything up, likely I use the wrogn search terms. I assume someone must have written a plugin for that ...

I'm helping myself right now by defining "Editors" or in some cases "external tool configurations" but that is cumbersome and does not fit my needs.

It would be helpfull if you could use external tool configurations but execute them via right mouse menu on the selected resource.

Any idea welcom!

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to write a plugin for that...

Comment: I hoped someone knew such a plug in as all my attempts to google for one failed ;D

Answer (score 0):

I found this Plugin by accident: http://pluginbox.sourceforge.net/plugins.html it seems it is very close to what I wanted.